# why i get E11000 node js mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

why when i try to post i get this error :

error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.news index: user.name_1 dup key: { user.name: null } message=E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.news index: user.name_1 dup key: { user.name: null }, stack=MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.news index: user.name_1 dup key: { user.name: null }

my model is this :

[image]

Comment: i found the solution just i add unique:true one for the user  another for artiste..then i delte a document from mongodb then i post and all is well

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your collection was created with index on user.name: 1 , { unique: true } , and when you try to insert document without the user.name value  you succeed with the first record causing user.name: null to be inserted , but when you insert second record it complain that there is already user.name: null with the error: E11000 ( duplicate key )